# MySQL Error #1215 on Many to Many relationship creation

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a simple many-to-many relationship between 2 tables, "master" and "options". I Keep getting "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint" when trying to import using phpMyAdmin. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code, ideas? FYI, I can create one-to-many relationships just fine but not a many to many.

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- Mon Apr 16 14:44:57 2018
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Master`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Master` (
  `Master_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Options` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Master_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Options`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Options` (
  `Options_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Options` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Options_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`Master_Options`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`Master_Options` (
  `Master_ID` INT NULL,
  `Options_ID` INT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_Master_Options_Master_idx` (`Master_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Master_Options_Options1_idx` (`Options_ID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Master_Options_Master`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Master_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Master` (`Options`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Master_Options_Options1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Options_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Options` (`Options_ID`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Typo: The `Master_ID` foreign key should reference `Master_ID`, not `Options`.

Comment: Sorry bad naming convention but that's intended. The options field needs to reference many different options so that's why i'm trying to create a many to many relationship. I am going to add more fields that need many to many relationships in the master table but I wanted to get one working before I add the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you haven't defined indexes on the referenced columns.

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

and

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any column or group of
>   columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index
>   where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the
>   same order.

There are no indexes defined for the `Options` columns in either the `Master` or `Options` tables. This will cause the error you are getting.

Also,

> Additionally, MySQL requires that the referenced columns be indexed
>   for performance reasons. However, the system does not enforce a
>   requirement that the referenced columns be UNIQUE or be declared NOT
>   NULL. The handling of foreign key references to nonunique keys or keys
>   that contain NULL values is not well defined for operations such as
>   UPDATE or DELETE CASCADE. You are advised to use foreign keys that
>   reference only UNIQUE (including PRIMARY) and NOT NULL keys.

Both `Options` columns allow NULL and you haven't defined them as UNIQUE. This won't stop you creating the FKs but will probably mean that when you do they won't work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer (i'll mark it as such) although It's a bit over my head since i'm very new to MYSQL. I suppose I need to watch some Youtube tutorials to learn how to create many-to-many relationships correctly or unnormalize my tables. Any videos or tutorials you would recommend?

Comment: You were very nearly there anyway. The point about a M-2-M relationship is that your join table should reference UNIQUE values in the referenced tables. These will be the Primary Keys. So the definition of the first constraint in master_options should read CONSTRAINT `fk_Master_Options_Master`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Master_ID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Master` (`Master_ID`)  etc. These PKs are indexed by definition, you were referencing another field that wasn't indexed so the constraint definition failed.